# Ember data sideloaded models ignored

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I'm new to Ember, and am having a problem I'm not seeing duplicated anywhere else so I'm sure I'm doing something silly. I have these models:

```
App.User = DS.Model.extend({
    username: DS.attr("string"),
    userId: DS.attr("number"),
    modules: DS.hasMany("App.Module")
});
App.Module = DS.Model.extend({
    moduleId: DS.attr("number"),
    name: DS.attr("string")
});
```

Note that my Module model is simply a container that a User can have a few of, and many users might share the same modules - they're actually represented by an Enum on the server. As such, the backend does not have a mapping of Module > Users, so I've left the DS.ownedBy or DS.hasMany out of App.Module. I have, however, tried my test with a "users: DS.hasMany('App.User')" in there as well, with the same result. If it turns out to be necessary, I could maintain such a mapping, but I have no other reason for doing so right now, so it would be a bit unfortunate to be forced to add such a table to my database.

I'm using Ember.Auth for authentication, and when my app loads up and I log in, the server requests (as expected):

```
users/nathan?authToken=<token>
```

The result is also as I think it should be, according to the ember data docs:

```
{
    "user": {
        "username": "nathan",
        "user_id": 1,
        "module_ids": [1,2]
    },
    "modules": [
        {"module_id": 1, "name": "Account Settings"},
        {"module_id": 2, "name": "Manage Websites"}
    ]
}
```

I'm then testing in the Chrome console with:

```
App.Auth.get("user").get("modules");
```

or

```
App.User.find("nathan").get("modules");
```

and in both cases, Ember makes a request to my server to get the data for Modules 1 and 2. If I repeat the same request, it doesn't go back to the server again, so it is storing the result properly that time, it's simply the sideload that it's ignoring.

I'm using ember-1.0.0-rc4 with ember-data-0.13.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your sideload response, `module_id` should be `id`.

(or you can configure `ember-data` to use `module_id`, but formatting the server response should be the easier way?)

--- edit for explanation ---

I'm not sure the original `REST` call is "working perfectly". Without the `id`. `ember-data` does see the two `module`s that your originally sideloaded, but it sees no `id`, so it does not know that they are `module`s `1` and `2` respectively. By default (changeable), `ember-data` expects the `id` to be called `id`; your `module_id` (and `user_id`) are just treated as regular properties.

On your next API call (to `/modules?ids[]=1&ids[]=2` presumably), `ember-data` silently assumes that, since your requested two `module`s, and two `module`s came back, they should be the two that you requested. Try sending back this

```
{
    "modules": [
        {"module_id": 3, "name": "Foo module"},
        {"module_id": 4, "name": "Bar module"}
    ]
}
```

for the request `/modules?ids[]=1&ids[]=2`, you will *still* get your "successful" observation.

Try `App.Module.find(1).get('name')` with the `module_id`-response - you will get `undefined`; now try it with the `id`-response, and you will get `Account settings` as expected.

Comment: This fixed it, but I find this answer unsatisfying: Why did this fix it, when the system was OK with "module_id" on a regular find REST call? (since it wouldn't fetch it a second time if I did the find() twice) That's an annoying inconsistency.

Comment: @roguenet explanation added. In short, your original scenario is not actually "working perfectly" as you expected it to.

Comment: Ah ha, I'd suspected there might be something like that going on after your fix got things working for me and I thought about it a bit. Thanks for the confirmation!

Answer (score 0):

Have you configured your RestAdapter to sideload modules?

Like this:

```
DS.RESTAdapter.configure('App.Module', {
  sideloadsAs: 'modules'
});
```

Comment: Doing this, I get this error at runtime, presumably because "modules" is supposed to be the default given the Models above: "assertion failed: The 'modules' alias has already been defined"